# Задача с ферзями

Tags: c++

есть задача:

8*8 доске для шахмат располагают - N ферзей так, чтобы они не могли побить друг друга (не могут быть в одном столбце, ряду или диагонали).

Нужно найти сколькими способами можно расположить N ферзей чтобы они не могли аттаковать друг друга.

Допустим ввод 8 а вывод соответственно 92

Вот что удалось написать:
И если не трудно прокомментрируйте свой код хотябы минимально, спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n = 0; //количество ферзей
int board[8][8]; // 0 - не бьет ячейку, 1 - бьет

void set_queen(int i, int j)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k) {
        ++board[k][j]; //прибавляем горизонталь
        ++board[i][k]; //прибавляем диагональ

        int foo = j - i + k; // диагональ №1
        if(foo >= 0 && foo < 8)//прибавляем диагональ №1
            ++board[k][foo];

        foo = j+i-k; //диагональ №2
        if(foo >= 0 && foo < 8)//прибавляем диагональ №2
            ++board[k][foo];
    }
    board[i][j] = -1; // -1 = тут стоит ферзь
}

void reset_queen(int i, int j)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k) {
        -board[k][j]; //прибавляем горизонталь
        --board[i][k]; //прибавляем диагональ

        int foo = j - i + k; // диагональ №1
        if(foo >= 0 && foo < 8)//прибавляем диагональ №1
            --board[k][foo];

        foo = j+i-k; //диагональ №2
        if(foo >= 0 && foo < 8)//прибавляем диагональ №2
            --board[k][foo];
    }
    board[i][j] = 0; // возвращаем 0
}

bool try_set_queen(int i) // пытаемся поставить на iй столбец
{
    bool res = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        if (board[i][j] == 0) // если ячейку не бьют
        {
            set_queen(i,j);
            if(i == 7) //если мы поставили всех ферзей
                res = true;
            else // если не получилось поставить - ставим на i+1
                if(!(res = try_set_queen(i+1))) // если не получилось поставить на следующий стобец ферзя
                    reset_queen(i,j); // убираем его с позиции i j
        }
        if(res) // если удалось поставить на одну из ячеек
            break;
    }
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    try_set_queen(0);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            if(board[i][j] == 0)
                sum++;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. ферзей может быть меньше, чем размер доски?

Comment: в коде явно все завязано на то, что размер доски 8х8. Лучше это вынести глобальной константой/define.

Comment: Да, и для какого диапазона размеров доски надо считать?

Comment: И еще — рекомендую вот эту статью: https://habr.com/ru/post/343738/ И снова — у вас `n` и `N` в условии различные числа или одно и то же?

Comment: @KoVadim доска 8х8, сейчас подкорректирую

Comment: n - размер доски, уже убрал, там 8х8
N - количество ферзей

Comment: Только что добавил **Часть 3** [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1356368/267338), где ускорил код в **40-50 раз** сделав все оптимизации. Обратите внимание. И очень интересно что сейчас вернёт тестовая система, все ли 100% тестов пройдут. Кстати не забудьте увеличить максимальные возможные пределы массива, если у вас большие входные размеры доски. Сейчас пределы 16х16 доска, если в тестах есть больше доски, то выставьте их, это настраивается в моём коде внутри `enum` который задаёт `max_rows` (максимальное число рядов в доске) и `max_cols` (максимальное число колонок доски).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Часть 1** (смотрите часть 2 ниже)

Возможно вы хотели, чтобы в ответ мы прокомментировали ваше решение, или нашли ошибки. Я решил в качестве ответа реализовать своё решение, может пригодится, например для сравнения ответов.

У вас очень интересная и супер известная задача, был рад только что с нуля написать очередной раз её решение, я эту задачу уже несколько раз писал. Решил конечно классическим подходом через подход называемый [Поиск с возвратом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) (Back-tracking в английском).

Задачу решил для доски любого размера, не только 8х8, причём у меня поддерживается даже не квадратная (прямоугольная) доска. Задать размеры можно в первой строке main(), константы `rows` (число рядов) и `cols` (число столбцов) и `N` - количество расставляемых ферзей.

Также решил красиво визуализировать все решения в виде отрисовки досок в консоле. После кода ниже смотрите пример вывода консоли, где выводятся доски-решения, промотайте в самый конец вывода, там выведено количество решений `Number of solutions: 92` (92 для случая 8x8 доски и 8 ферзей). Если нужно вывести только число решений, но не выводить сами доски, то не далеко от начала функции Solve() замените `if (1) {` на `if (0) {`.

Весь код детально прокомментирован на русском.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/8r89M9fv1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void Output(std::vector<std::vector<bool>> & board, std::vector<std::string> & lines, bool last);

// Рекурсивная функция для решения бэк-трэкингом.
// board - доска, board[i][j] == true если стоит ферзь в [i][j], иначе false.
// lines - вспомогательный массив для сбора выводимых в консоль строк.
// N - количество ферзей, cnt - сколько ферзей уже удалось расставить
// (start_i, start_j) - с какой позиции пытаться расставлять следующего ферзя
void Solve(std::vector<std::vector<bool>> & board, std::vector<std::string> & lines,
        int N, int & num_sol, int cnt = 0, int start_i = 0, int start_j = 0, int depth = 0) {
    if (cnt >= N) {
        Output(board, lines, false);
        // Увеличиваем счётчик числа решений.
        ++num_sol;
        return;
    }
            
    // Обходим всю доску, начиная с позиции последнего ферзя.
    for (int i = start_i; i < board.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = i == start_i ? start_j : 0; j < board[i].size(); ++j) {
            bool attacked = false;
            // Цикл по k проверяет атакована ли позиция [i][j]
            for (int k = 0; k < (board.size() > board[i].size() ?
                    board.size() : board[i].size()); ++k)
                if (
                    // Есть ли атака по горизонтали
                    k < board[i].size() && k != j && board[i][k] ||
                    // Атака по вертикали
                    k < board.size() && k != i && board[k][j] ||
                    // Атака по главной диагонали
                    k < board.size() && k != i && 0 <= j - i + k &&
                        j - i + k < board[i].size() && board[k][j - i + k] ||
                    // Атака по второстепенной диагонали
                    k < board.size() && k != i && 0 <= j + i - k &&
                        j + i - k < board[i].size() && board[k][j + i - k]
                ) {
                    attacked = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (attacked)
                continue;
            // Позиция [i][j] не под атакой, потому ставим ферзя
            board[i][j] = true;
            // Рекурисвный спуск для расстановки следующего ферзя
            Solve(board, lines, N, num_sol, cnt + 1, i, j + 1, depth + 1);
            // Бэктрэкинг, удаляем прошлого установленного ферзя
            board[i][j] = false;
        }
    if (depth == 0)
        Output(board, lines, true);
}

// Функция для вывода решений.
void Output(std::vector<std::vector<bool>> & board, std::vector<std::string> & lines, bool last) {
    // Вывод решения в консоль. Поставить тут if (0) если не нужно выводить доски в консоль.
    if (1) {
        if (!last) {
            // Добавление одной доски к текущим строкам.
            for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); ++j)
                    lines[i].push_back(board[i][j] ? 'Q' : '.');
                // Символ | в качестве разделителя между досок.
                lines[i] += "|";
            }
        }
        // Если длина строк превысила ширину консоли (70), то выводим строки и разделитель.
        if (lines.at(0).size() >= 70 || last && !lines.at(0).empty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
                std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.at(0).size(); ++j)
                std::cout << (lines.at(0)[j] == '|' ? '+' : '-');
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // Очищаем строки для следующих выводов досок.
            lines.clear();
            lines.resize(board.size());
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    // Входные параметры, rows - число рядов доски, cols - число столбцов
    // N - число ферзей которые нужно расставить
    int const rows = 8, cols = 8, N = 8;
    // Заполняем пустыми значениями доску размером [rows][cols]
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> board(rows, std::vector<bool>(cols));
    std::vector<std::string> lines(rows);
    // Ответ, число решений
    int num_sol = 0;
    // Запускаем бэк-трэкинг поиск решений.
    Solve(board, lines, N, num_sol);
    // Вывод ответа.
    std::cout << "Number of solutions: " << num_sol << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод консоли (общее число решений в конце):

```
Q.......|Q.......|Q.......|Q.......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|
....Q...|.....Q..|......Q.|......Q.|...Q....|....Q...|....Q...|.....Q..|
.......Q|.......Q|...Q....|....Q...|.....Q..|......Q.|......Q.|Q.......|
.....Q..|..Q.....|.....Q..|.......Q|.......Q|Q.......|...Q....|......Q.|
..Q.....|......Q.|.......Q|.Q......|..Q.....|..Q.....|Q.......|...Q....|
......Q.|...Q....|.Q......|...Q....|Q.......|.......Q|.......Q|.......Q|
.Q......|.Q......|....Q...|.....Q..|......Q.|.....Q..|.....Q..|..Q.....|
...Q....|....Q...|..Q.....|..Q.....|....Q...|...Q....|..Q.....|....Q...|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|
.....Q..|......Q.|......Q.|.......Q|Q.......|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|
.......Q|..Q.....|....Q...|.....Q..|......Q.|.Q......|.Q......|......Q.|
..Q.....|.....Q..|.......Q|Q.......|....Q...|.......Q|.......Q|Q.......|
Q.......|.......Q|Q.......|..Q.....|.......Q|Q.......|.....Q..|...Q....|
...Q....|....Q...|...Q....|....Q...|.Q......|......Q.|...Q....|.Q......|
......Q.|Q.......|.....Q..|......Q.|...Q....|...Q....|......Q.|.......Q|
....Q...|...Q....|..Q.....|...Q....|.....Q..|.....Q..|Q.......|.....Q..|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|
....Q...|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|
.......Q|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|...Q....|...Q....|.......Q|.......Q|
...Q....|....Q...|......Q.|......Q.|Q.......|.Q......|Q.......|Q.......|
Q.......|.......Q|Q.......|....Q...|.......Q|.......Q|...Q....|....Q...|
......Q.|Q.......|...Q....|Q.......|....Q...|....Q...|......Q.|......Q.|
.Q......|......Q.|.......Q|.......Q|......Q.|......Q.|....Q...|.Q......|
.....Q..|...Q....|....Q...|...Q....|.Q......|Q.......|.Q......|...Q....|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|
.....Q..|......Q.|......Q.|.......Q|Q.......|Q.......|.Q......|.Q......|
.......Q|.Q......|.Q......|...Q....|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|......Q.|
.Q......|.......Q|.......Q|......Q.|.......Q|.......Q|.......Q|..Q.....|
...Q....|....Q...|.....Q..|Q.......|.Q......|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|
Q.......|Q.......|...Q....|.....Q..|......Q.|..Q.....|Q.......|.......Q|
......Q.|...Q....|Q.......|.Q......|..Q.....|......Q.|..Q.....|Q.......|
....Q...|.....Q..|....Q...|....Q...|.....Q..|.Q......|......Q.|....Q...|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|
.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|......Q.|
......Q.|......Q.|.......Q|.......Q|Q.......|.......Q|.......Q|Q.......|
..Q.....|....Q...|....Q...|.....Q..|....Q...|.Q......|..Q.....|.......Q|
.....Q..|Q.......|......Q.|Q.......|.Q......|......Q.|Q.......|....Q...|
.......Q|.......Q|Q.......|..Q.....|.......Q|Q.......|......Q.|.Q......|
....Q...|.....Q..|..Q.....|....Q...|..Q.....|..Q.....|....Q...|.....Q..|
Q.......|..Q.....|.....Q..|......Q.|......Q.|....Q...|.Q......|..Q.....|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|....Q...|....Q...|
......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|.......Q|.......Q|.......Q|Q.......|Q.......|
..Q.....|....Q...|....Q...|Q.......|Q.......|....Q...|...Q....|.......Q|
.......Q|.Q......|..Q.....|..Q.....|....Q...|..Q.....|.....Q..|...Q....|
.Q......|.....Q..|Q.......|.....Q..|......Q.|Q.......|.......Q|.Q......|
....Q...|Q.......|.....Q..|.Q......|.Q......|......Q.|.Q......|......Q.|
Q.......|..Q.....|.......Q|......Q.|.....Q..|.Q......|......Q.|..Q.....|
.....Q..|.......Q|.Q......|....Q...|..Q.....|.....Q..|..Q.....|.....Q..|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|
Q.......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|
.......Q|...Q....|...Q....|.....Q..|.......Q|Q.......|Q.......|.......Q|
.....Q..|.....Q..|......Q.|Q.......|Q.......|.....Q..|......Q.|...Q....|
..Q.....|.......Q|..Q.....|......Q.|...Q....|.......Q|.Q......|......Q.|
......Q.|..Q.....|.......Q|...Q....|......Q.|.Q......|.......Q|Q.......|
.Q......|Q.......|.....Q..|.......Q|..Q.....|...Q....|.....Q..|.....Q..|
...Q....|......Q.|Q.......|..Q.....|.....Q..|......Q.|...Q....|.Q......|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|....Q...|
......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|.......Q|.......Q|
Q.......|Q.......|.Q......|.Q......|.Q......|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|
..Q.....|...Q....|...Q....|.....Q..|.....Q..|Q.......|Q.......|Q.......|
.......Q|.Q......|.......Q|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|......Q.|
.....Q..|.......Q|Q.......|Q.......|Q.......|.......Q|.....Q..|.Q......|
...Q....|.....Q..|..Q.....|...Q....|.......Q|.....Q..|.Q......|.....Q..|
.Q......|..Q.....|.....Q..|.......Q|...Q....|.Q......|......Q.|..Q.....|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|
Q.......|.Q......|.Q......|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|
....Q...|......Q.|......Q.|Q.......|Q.......|Q.......|....Q...|....Q...|
.Q......|Q.......|Q.......|......Q.|.......Q|.......Q|......Q.|.......Q|
.......Q|..Q.....|...Q....|....Q...|...Q....|....Q...|Q.......|Q.......|
..Q.....|....Q...|.......Q|.......Q|.Q......|.Q......|...Q....|...Q....|
......Q.|.......Q|....Q...|.Q......|......Q.|...Q....|.Q......|.Q......|
...Q....|...Q....|..Q.....|...Q....|....Q...|......Q.|.......Q|......Q.|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|.....Q..|
..Q.....|..Q.....|..Q.....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|...Q....|.......Q|
......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|Q.......|.Q......|......Q.|......Q.|.Q......|
.Q......|.Q......|...Q....|....Q...|.......Q|Q.......|Q.......|...Q....|
...Q....|.......Q|Q.......|.......Q|....Q...|..Q.....|.......Q|Q.......|
.......Q|....Q...|.......Q|.Q......|......Q.|....Q...|.Q......|......Q.|
Q.......|Q.......|.Q......|......Q.|Q.......|.Q......|....Q...|....Q...|
....Q...|...Q....|....Q...|..Q.....|..Q.....|.......Q|..Q.....|..Q.....|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|......Q.|
Q.......|.Q......|.Q......|..Q.....|..Q.....|...Q....|...Q....|....Q...|
..Q.....|...Q....|.....Q..|Q.......|.......Q|.Q......|.Q......|..Q.....|
.......Q|Q.......|..Q.....|.....Q..|.Q......|....Q...|.......Q|Q.......|
.....Q..|.......Q|Q.......|.......Q|....Q...|.......Q|.....Q..|.....Q..|
...Q....|....Q...|...Q....|....Q...|Q.......|Q.......|Q.......|.......Q|
.Q......|..Q.....|.......Q|.Q......|.....Q..|..Q.....|..Q.....|.Q......|
....Q...|.....Q..|....Q...|...Q....|...Q....|.....Q..|....Q...|...Q....|
--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
.......Q|.......Q|.......Q|.......Q|
.Q......|.Q......|..Q.....|...Q....|
...Q....|....Q...|Q.......|Q.......|
Q.......|..Q.....|.....Q..|..Q.....|
......Q.|Q.......|.Q......|.....Q..|
....Q...|......Q.|....Q...|.Q......|
..Q.....|...Q....|......Q.|......Q.|
.....Q..|.....Q..|...Q....|....Q...|
--------+--------+--------+--------+
Number of solutions: 92
```

---

**Часть 2** (Часть 3 ниже)

По просьбе автора вопроса упростил решение из Части 1, чтобы не использовать `std::vector`, вместо этого использовал обычные Си массивы.

Замечание - размерности Си массива я сделал с запасом, больше чем требует задача, это сделано потому, что размерности Си массива требуется указывать константами этапа компиляции, а реальные размеры задачи (число рядов и столбцов) уже можно запросить у пользователя при старте программы прочитав их из `std::cin`. Также заметьте что размерности заданы через `enum` в начале программы, если `enum` не допустим, то можно их задать и через макросы `#define max_rows 16` и `#define max_cols 16` или просто вбить в код числа в местах использования `max_rows` и `max_cols`.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/Wfh6bjExW)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Максимальное допустимое число рядов и колонок на доске
enum { max_rows = 16, max_cols = 16 };

// Декларирование функции Output, определённой ниже.
void Output(bool (& board)[max_rows][max_cols], std::string (& lines)[max_rows],
    int rows, int cols, bool last);

// Рекурсивная функция для решения бэк-трэкингом.
// board - доска, board[i][j] == true если стоит ферзь в [i][j], иначе false.
// lines - вспомогательный массив для сбора выводимых в консоль строк.
// N - количество ферзей, cnt - сколько ферзей уже удалось расставить
// (start_i, start_j) - с какой позиции пытаться расставлять следующего ферзя
void Solve(bool (& board)[max_rows][max_cols], std::string (& lines)[max_rows],
        int rows, int cols, int N, int & num_sol, int cnt = 0, int start_i = 0,
        int start_j = 0, int depth = 0) {
            
    if (cnt >= N) {
        Output(board, lines, rows, cols, false);
        // Увеличиваем счётчик числа решений.
        ++num_sol;
        return;
    }
            
    // Обходим всю доску, начиная с позиции последнего ферзя.
    for (int i = start_i; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int j = i == start_i ? start_j : 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            bool attacked = false;
            // Цикл по k проверяет атакована ли позиция [i][j]
            for (int k = 0; k < (rows > cols ? rows : cols); ++k)
                if (
                    // Есть ли атака по горизонтали
                    k < cols && k != j && board[i][k] ||
                    // Атака по вертикали
                    k < rows && k != i && board[k][j] ||
                    // Атака по главной диагонали
                    k < rows && k != i && 0 <= j - i + k &&
                        j - i + k < cols && board[k][j - i + k] ||
                    // Атака по второстепенной диагонали
                    k < rows && k != i && 0 <= j + i - k &&
                        j + i - k < cols && board[k][j + i - k]
                ) {
                    // Ферзь в позиции [i][j] под атакой.
                    attacked = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (attacked)
                continue;
            // Позиция [i][j] не под атакой, потому ставим ферзя
            board[i][j] = true;
            // Рекурисвный спуск для расстановки следующего ферзя
            Solve(board, lines, rows, cols, N, num_sol, cnt + 1, i, j + 1, depth + 1);
            // Бэктрэкинг, удаляем прошлого установленного ферзя
            board[i][j] = false;
        }
    if (depth == 0)
        Output(board, lines, rows, cols, true);
}

// Функция для вывода решений.
void Output(bool (& board)[max_rows][max_cols], std::string (& lines)[max_rows],
        int rows, int cols, bool last) {
    // Вывод решения в консоль. Поставить тут if (0) если не нужно выводить доски в консоль.
    if (1) {
        if (!last) {
            // Добавление одной доски к текущим строкам.
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
                    lines[i].push_back(board[i][j] ? 'Q' : '.');
                // Символ | в качестве разделителя между досок.
                lines[i] += "|";
            }
        }
        // Если длина строк превысила ширину консоли (70), то выводим строки и разделитель.
        if (lines[0].size() >= 70 || last && !lines[0].empty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines[0].size(); ++j)
                std::cout << (lines[0][j] == '|' ? '+' : '-');
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // Очищаем строки для следующих выводов досок.
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                lines[i].clear();
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    // Входные параметры, rows - число рядов доски, cols - число столбцов
    // N - число ферзей которые нужно расставить
    int const rows = 8, cols = 8, N = 8;
    // Заполняем пустыми значениями доску размером [rows][cols]
    bool board[max_rows][max_cols] = {};
    std::string lines[max_rows] = {};
    // Ответ, число решений
    int num_sol = 0;
    // Запускаем бэк-трэкинг поиск решений.
    Solve(board, lines, rows, cols, N, num_sol);
    // Вывод ответа.
    std::cout << "Number of solutions: " << num_sol << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод консоли такой же как в Части 1.

---

**Часть 3**

Как выяснилось есть ограничения по времени, и решение из Части 2 проходило по времени только на 70% тестах. Решил сделать значительные оптимизации.

А именно вместо внутреннего цикла по k сделал пометки занятых вертикалей и диагоналей с помощью bool-массивов.

После того как k-цикл убран скорость программы должна возрасти примерно в **40-50 раз**.

**Update**. Только что ещё две оптимизации сделал - 1) преждевременный выход, если свободных рядов или колонок не хватает для оставшихся ферзей, 2) сбор свободных колонок в отдельный массив чтобы в несколько раз ускорить внутренний цикл по `j`. Обе эти оптимизации ещё **раз в 3-5** ускоряют всё.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/KK6qGPK6q)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) >= (b) ? (a) : (b))

// Максимальное допустимое число рядов и колонок на доске
enum { max_rows = 32, max_cols = 32, max_max_rows_cols = MAX(max_rows, max_cols) };

// Декларирование функции Output, определённой ниже.
void Output(bool (& board)[max_rows][max_cols], std::string (& lines)[max_rows],
    int rows, int cols, bool last);

// Рекурсивная функция для решения бэк-трэкингом.
// board - доска, board[i][j] == true если стоит ферзь в [i][j], иначе false.
// lines - вспомогательный массив для сбора выводимых в консоль строк.
// N - количество ферзей, cnt - сколько ферзей уже удалось расставить
// (start_i, start_j) - с какой позиции пытаться расставлять следующего ферзя
void Solve(bool (& board)[max_rows][max_cols], std::string (& lines)[max_rows],
        bool (& busy_cols)[max_cols], bool (& busy_diagA)[2 * max_max_rows_cols],
        bool (& busy_diagB)[2 * max_max_rows_cols],
        int rows, int cols, int N, int & num_sol, int cnt = 0, int start_i = 0, int depth = 0) {
            
    if (cnt >= N) {
        Output(board, lines, rows, cols, false);
        // Увеличиваем счётчик числа решений.
        ++num_sol;
        return;
    }
    
    int const max_rows_cols = MAX(rows, cols);
    
    // Больше не хватаят свободных рядов для расстановки оставшихся ферзей.
    if (rows - start_i < N - cnt)
        return;

    // Выписываем все свободные столбцы, нам это потом даст ускорение.
    int avail_cols[max_cols];
    int avail_cols_cnt = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        if (!busy_cols[j]) {
            avail_cols[avail_cols_cnt] = j;
            ++avail_cols_cnt;
        }
    // Больше не хватаят свободных столбцов для расстановки оставшихся ферзей.
    if (avail_cols_cnt < N - cnt)
        return;
    
    // Обходим всю доску, начиная со следующего ряда после последнего ферзя.
    for (int i = start_i; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int jj = 0; jj < avail_cols_cnt; ++jj) {
            int const j = avail_cols[jj];
            
            // Пропускаем занаятые диагонали. Вертикаль уже не надо проверять.
            if (busy_diagA[max_rows_cols + j - i] || busy_diagB[j + i])
                continue;
            
            // Больше проверок атаки не нужно.
            
            // Позиция [i][j] не под атакой, потому ставим ферзя
            board[i][j] = true;
            // Помечаем j-й столбец занятым.
            busy_cols[j] = true;
            // Помечаем главную диагональ занятой.
            busy_diagA[max_rows_cols + j - i] = true;
            // Помечаем второстепенную диагональ занятой.
            busy_diagB[j + i] = true;
            
            // Рекурисвный спуск для расстановки следующего ферзя
            Solve(board, lines, busy_cols, busy_diagA, busy_diagB,
                rows, cols, N, num_sol, cnt + 1, i + 1, depth + 1);
            
            // Бэктрэкинг, удаляем прошлого установленного ферзя
            board[i][j] = false;
            // Убираем пометки вертикали, и диагоналей.
            busy_cols[j] = false;
            busy_diagA[max_rows_cols + j - i] = false;
            busy_diagB[j + i] = false;
        }
    if (depth == 0)
        Output(board, lines, rows, cols, true);
}

// Функция для вывода решений.
void Output(bool (& board)[max_rows][max_cols], std::string (& lines)[max_rows],
        int rows, int cols, bool last) {
    // Вывод решения в консоль. Поставить тут if (0) если не нужно выводить доски в консоль.
    if (1) {
        if (!last) {
            // Добавление одной доски к текущим строкам.
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
                    lines[i].push_back(board[i][j] ? 'Q' : '.');
                // Символ | в качестве разделителя между досок.
                lines[i] += "|";
            }
        }
        // Если длина строк превысила ширину консоли (70), то выводим строки и разделитель.
        if (lines[0].size() >= 70 || last && !lines[0].empty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines[0].size(); ++j)
                std::cout << (lines[0][j] == '|' ? '+' : '-');
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // Очищаем строки для следующих выводов досок.
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                lines[i].clear();
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    // Входные параметры, rows - число рядов доски, cols - число столбцов
    // N - число ферзей которые нужно расставить
    int const rows = 8, cols = 8, N = 8;
    // Заполняем пустыми значениями доску размером [rows][cols]
    bool board[max_rows][max_cols] = {};
    std::string lines[max_rows] = {};
    // Следующие массивы указывают, заняты ли вертикаль и диагонали.
    bool busy_cols[max_cols] = {};
    bool busy_diagA[2 * max_max_rows_cols] = {};
    bool busy_diagB[2 * max_max_rows_cols] = {};
    // Ответ, число решений
    int num_sol = 0;
    // Запускаем бэк-трэкинг поиск решений.
    Solve(board, lines, busy_cols, busy_diagA, busy_diagB, rows, cols, N, num_sol);
    // Вывод ответа.
    std::cout << "Number of solutions: " << num_sol << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод консоли как в Части 1.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131990/discussion-on-answer-by-arty---).